# Javascript: display not changing from "block" to "none"

Tags: javascript

After clicking `elements` (the red square), the `func` function gets called and it gets the first child node, then that node changes It's children display to `block`. Now, I'm trying to set them back to `none` after clicking `background_dim` (the dark background) by getting `background_dim`'s parent node, then iterating throught the children and setting their display to `none`. But apparently this doesn't work. It only works If I set their position to `relative`, but I'd have to change the other function as well.

```js
function func(element) {
  var _first_child = element.children[0];
  for (var i = 0; i < _first_child.children.length; ++i)
    _first_child.children[i].style.display = "block";
}

function func_t(element) {
  var _parent = element.parentNode;
  for (var i = 0; i < _parent.children.length; ++i)
    _parent.children[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.elements {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
}

.background {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.display-container
{
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 30%;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  
}
```

```html
<html>

  <body>
    <ul>
      <li class="elements" onclick="func(this);">
        <div class="_display_job_dim_">
          <div class="background" onclick="func_t(this);"></div>
          <div class="display-container"></div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
 
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/waxebm81/285/

Comment: Do you actually want the `.parentNode.parentNode`? e.g. 2 levels up to get back to the `LI` element?

Comment: You know straightfoward Javascript can be edited in place on stack overflow - and then people can run the snippet directly right? iIt's the icon that looks like this [<>] You'll get quicker answers that way

Comment: No. I wanna get to ``display_job_dim`` element, then iterating throught It's children to set their display back to ``none``

Comment: Sorry. I've never asked a Javascript question before. I will try to edit it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that if a click happens on `background_dim` it will by default propagate up in the DOM, so after `func_t` was called, the event will propagate to `.elements` and `func(this)` is called which will show the elements again.

So you ned to stop the propagation of the event:

```js
document.querySelector('.elements').addEventListener('click', func, false)
document.querySelector('.background_dim').addEventListener('click', func_t, false)


function func(evt) {
  evt.stopPropagation();
  var element = evt.target;
  var _first_child = element.children[0];
  for (var i = 0; i < _first_child.children.length; ++i) {
    _first_child.children[i].style.display = "block";
  }

}

function func_t(evt) {
  evt.stopPropagation();
  var element = evt.target;
  var _parent = element.parentNode;
  for (var i = 0; i < _parent.children.length; ++i) {
    _parent.children[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  return false;
}
```

```css
.elements {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
}

.background_dim {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.display-container {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: 30%;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li class="elements">
      <div class="_display_job_dim_">
        <div class="background_dim"></div>
        <div class="display-container"></div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How does it propagate to ``elements`` since it never gets there? Isn't ``parentNode`` referring to ``_display_job_dim``? Also, every ``li`` element will be having these 2 elements. Wouldn't hardcoding in the ``click`` functions trigger all of them at once?

Comment: @VioAriton `.background_dim` is descendant of `.elements`, so when the click happens on `.background_dim` it will propagate through its ancestor until the propagation is stopped.